Get the Last Date of a Google Big Query Record
I have a data set with multiple rows within a dataset that are duplicated. I am trying to use MAX and Group By.
Below is a snippet of what I am running. I am not receiving an error, but it is not correct.
This is still giving me multiple records with different dates. It is removing the oldest record, but I only want to get the highest datetime if possible.
SELECT DISTINCT event_name, acct_id, upd_datetime, paid, MAX(datetime) as date
FROM `Table` 
GROUP BY acct_id, event_name, upd_datetime, paid
ORDER BY date desc

